# DICOM Tag - How to detect human x-ray versus techn. x-ray

Tags: dicom

Is there a DICOM tag that determines whether it is a **human radiograph** (HWS, LWS, ...) or a **technical radiograph (specimen)** DICOM file / DICOM image.

EDIT 
In between I checked this link 
https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/hemodynamic/patient/00102202/00080100

I don't found any DICOM tag that help me out.

Comment: Thanks for downvote. Why is there no comment whats wrong with the question.

Comment: I find these unreliable. phantoms are often scanned with the wrong info entered on the equipment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are such keys:

- (0028,0300) Quality Control Image - Indicates whether or not this image is a quality control or phantom image. [NEMA](ftp://dicom.nema.org/MEDICAL/dicom/2016a/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.htm)
- (0050,0004) Calibration Image - Indicates whether a reference object (phantom) of known size is present in the image and was used for calibration. [NEMA](ftp://dicom.nema.org/MEDICAL/dicom/2016a/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.8.7.html)

However, I would suggest you not to rely on them too much, as they are not mandatory. Moreover, you cannot know whether proper examination protocol was set before taking the image.

Comment: Thanks! @Bartlomiej I found this Link https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/sc-image/general-image/00280300

Comment: Just to confirm the information in this answer. Whenever I have needed to make some random test images on an X-ray or CT machine, I've just keyed in a random patient ID and do my stuff. I also try to make sure, I don't send those images to a PACS or anywhere, but if they end up there, that's not a big problem, because they will not match to any actual patient ID anyway.

Comment: @Tarmo R Currently I have a collection from different hospitals without any lookup with patient ID. We try to analyse this DICOM tags.

Comment: What I have seen frequently is that the Patient Name / ID is set to values that help identifying technical images (e.g. "Consistency Check").